# How to force a Spring form to empty a list when no/fewer path values are submitted?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-form

**Setup:**

- Spring 4.3.5.RELEASE
- Tomcat 8.5.11
- Maven 4.0.0
- Java 1.8

**Project Background:**
I've a JSP that contains three tables. Two of the tables (titled: "*unselected*" and "*selected*") act very much like linked selected elements where they transfer rows between one another. The third table (titled: "*predefined*") is essentially used to add a pre-selected amount of items from the *unselected* table to the *selected* table. What ultimately matters here is that the *selected* table will contain multiple rows that have data attributes with a number associated.

Since it doesn't seem like there are Spring form tags that could peel the data attribute value from a table row, I have some Javascript that maintains hidden input elements to match the values that are in the *selected* table. This is in the format of: `<input type="hidden" id="selectedNumbers" name="selectedNumbers" value="1111"/>`. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvtmLuph/)).

Here are how the class and controller are set up:
**Class:**

```
    public class MyClass 
    {
        private List<Integer> selectedNumbers;

        public MyClass()
        {

        }

        public void setSelectedNumbers(List<Integer> selectedNumbers)
        {
            this.selectedNumbers = selectedNumbers;
        }

        public List<Integer> getSelectedNumbers()
        {
            return selectedNumbers;
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
    @Controller
    @SessionAttributes({"attributeOne", "attributeTwo"})
    @RequestMapping(value = "/mypage")
    public class MyController
    {
        @ModelAttribute
        private MyClass initMyClass()
        {
            return new MyClass();
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/mytablepage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getMyTablePage(Model model, @ModelAttribute("attributeOne") MyClass myClass)
        {
            return "mypage.mytablepage";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/mytablepage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String postMyTablePage(Model model, @ModelAttribute("attributeOne") MyClass myClass, BindingResult bindResult)
        {
            //Validate and check for bind errors.
            ...
            //End Validate and check for bind errors.

            return "redirect:nextpage.do";
        }
    }
```

The problem is largely that Spring seems to only perform a type of update on list values instead of recreating a list from scratch. This ends up causing remnant values that were removed to persist since there doesn't seem to be a way to have Spring delete removed values.

Here is an example of the scenario:

1. Add number 1111. [1111]
2. Add number 2222. [1111, 2222]
3. Add number 3333. [1111, 2222, 3333]
4. Add number 4444. [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444]
5. Continue to the next page. (Model attribute updates).

   - There were no previous values, so the list is [1111, 2222, 3333, 4444].
6. Return to the page.
7. Remove number 3333. [1111, 2222, 4444].
8. Remove number 1111. [2222, 4444].
9. Continue to the next page. (Model attribute updates).

   - We only sent across two values, so it updates the first two values in the list it had prior, resulting in [2222, 4444, 3333, 4444].

**Questions:**
Is there a way to force Spring to always create a new list or ensure that there are no remnant values that persist?

My current workaround is to never truly delete the values from the list; instead, I essentially null them and have a filter in my controller that compresses the list down by checking for null values and removing them. Is this even sane?

If anything doesn't make sense or doesn't actually reflect what I'm saying, please let me know. There's a lot involved that I've tried to minimize out, so there certainly could be some other factors causing this that I haven't thought of.